# grouping issue in case of empty data frame python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

```
Oncall_cntrl=Oncall_cntrl.groupby(['EMP NAME','SoW','Phase Name','EMPRemarks_Oncall','Location'],as_index=False)['HourInDecimal'].sum()


df_concat_Oncall=pd.concat([df_concat_OT, Oncall_cntrl],ignore_index=True)
```

This is fine when oncall_cntrl has observations , but sometimes when there is no call data this dataframe might be empty and as a results when group by its coming as empty dataframe without column structure, which results in concat issue in next step.

Could you please let me know atleast we should have column structure when oncall_cntrl df as empty . how do you do this so that i can concatenate in next step. Im stuck at this point.Kindly help.

Comment: Hard to say what the best option is without knowing why sometimes the `DataFrame` is empty and other times it's not. You could have whatever creates the empty DataFrame at least create one with the columns initialized. Or perhaps just check `if not df.empty` and only group if that's the case.

Comment: because if the employee project dont have oncall for that month this will be empty . sometimes he will work that time non empty

Comment: can you please help how we will do only group if it non empty any code snippet pls

Comment: Thanks alollz , got it. many thanks